# Avoid deleting databases by other users in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, kerberos, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm working on a Kerberos-enabled Hortonworks Data Platform 2.5 with Hive 1.2.1.

I just saw, that one user can create a database and another user can delete it!

```
[root@host ~]# su -l user1

[user1@host ~]# hive
 hive> create database user1db
 OK
 Time taken: 0.077 seconds
```

After creating this database, another user can login and delete it:

```
[root@host ~]# su -l user2

[user2@host ~]# hive
 hive> drop database user1db
 OK
 Time taken: 1.352 seconds
```

Why is this possible? Another user can also do other things like showing all databases etc.

How can this be avoided? Shouldn't there be a restriction like "only the creator is allowed to delete by default" or similar?

A user shouldn't be able to view / delete databases of other users!

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding:

- Give the permission to hive Database as 755 so that only owner can play with it, provided its a EXTERNAL hive table and data will be in HDFS.
- Enable the empty snapshots on warehouse of each user in HDFS (assuming /user/user1/warehouse, /user/user2/warehouse), details are https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsSnapshots.html